# Return integer value for time series dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I need to create a function whereby it returns a value for each row. This function is based on 2 other functions. For each entry in dataframe

```
def computeRSI (data, time_window = 14):
diff = data.diff(1).dropna()
up_chg = 0 * diff
down_chg = 0 * diff
up_chg[diff > 0] = diff[diff>0]
down_chg[diff < 0] = diff[diff<0]
up_chg_avg   = up_chg.ewm(com=time_window-1 , min_periods=time_window).mean()
down_chg_avg = down_chg.ewm(com=time_window-1 , min_periods=time_window).mean()

rs = abs(up_chg_avg/down_chg_avg)
rsi = 100 - 100/(1+rs)
return rsi

def computeCCI(data, time_window = 20):
TP = data.diff(1).dropna()
CCI = pd.Series((TP - TP.rolling(time_window).mean()) / (0.015 * TP.rolling(time_window).std()), name = 'CCI_' + str(time_window)) 
return CCI

def composite_indicator(data):
diff = data.diff(1).dropna()
if computeRSI(diff)>70 and computeCCI(diff)>100:
    return '+2'
elif computeRSI(diff)>60 and computeCCI(diff)>50:
    return '+1'
elif computeRSI(diff)<30 and computeCCI(diff)<-100:
    return '-2'
elif computeRSI(diff)<40 and computeCCI(diff)<-50:
    return '-1'
else:
    return '0'
```

My composite indicator function is giving me :
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I would like for there to return +2,+1,-2,-1,0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPWmR.png)

Comment: because you are passing a series rather than a individual number to if condition

Comment: The return value of `computeCCI()` is a Series, not a number.